# How can I install all files from GitHub repo with npm and ignore file field on package.json?

Tags: npm

I was using yarn in my project and use two git repositories as dependencies. Yarn get all the files from the GitHub repo, and ignore the field "files" in package.json or the `.npmignore` file.

Particullary I need the whole repo because. The reason is that I really need the generated stuff when I ran the commands there. I want to migrate to npm.